# After seeing suspicious error messages in log file

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

My log file has the message `The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be a possible hacking attempt` about 5 times a second for around 10 minutes. Clearly some sort of hack attempt. Should I be worried about this and what can I double check to make sure I'm being as secure as possible?

Comment: I am interested in this question!

Comment: Are you storing session in the database?

Comment: Nope I am not. I have a login page where I am using sessions, but not storing session data in the db.

Comment: Of course you need to look into this, because it could potentially be a hacking attempt. That said, I've had this error occur because of misconfiguration of my cookie settings, such as domain if I recall correctly. This was in an environment where hacking would have literally been impossible (local environment while disconnected from the internet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the database to store session information will protect you from people trying to manipulate their session data.  You can also encrypt the session data if you can't/don't want to store session in the database for whatever reason, or you could do both.

It's very simple to make these changes.  The documentation does a better job than I could of explaining how to set them up: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: And if they DID modify the cookie and you're using a database, they really can't do much of anything if you lock it to IP.

Comment: Right... the cookie only stores the ID of the session in the database so they just wouldn't be able to authenticate or anything if they changed the info in their cookie.